# React-Pro-Sidebar ver 1 Customization and Resizing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sidebar

I am building a web application that requires a sidebar for navigating and yet building one from scratch takes a lot of time since I'm still an amateur React developer.
Does anyone know and can help me with how to customize it and its sizing such as its paper, flex growing, padding, etc etc. ?

Here is my sidebar code:

```
<Sidebar 
   backgroundColor="#FAFAFA"
   height="100%"    
   width="220px"
   collapsedWidth="4.5rem"
   breakPoint='md'
   style={{
    height: '100%',
    top: 'auto',
    position: 'sticky',
    padding: '0rem',
    margin: '0rem',
   }}
    
    >
      <Menu 
          menuItemStyles={{
            button: ({ level, active }) => {
              if (level === 0 || level === 1 ) {
                return {
                  backgroundColor: active ? theme.palette.green[500] : undefined,
                  color: active ? 'white' :  undefined ,
                  "&:hover" : {
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette.green[500],
                    color:  'white',
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          }}
        >
        <MenuItem active={location.pathname === '/Home'} component={<Link to="/Home" />} icon={<HomeIcon />}> 
          <Typography variant="sidenav" >Home</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem active={location.pathname === '/Budgetproposal'} component={<Link to="/Budgetproposal" />} icon={<AccountBalanceIcon />}> 
          <Typography variant="sidenav" >Budget Proposal</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      
      </Sidebar>
```

And the attached image is the current sidebar i developed. [image: My Sidebar]

I wonder if someone can give me a detailed code on how can I resize it to smaller portions using rootstyles, sx, menuItemStyles, or its API since there is no detailed explanation from the github document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want resize the heigth of your sidebar you have to use the root className and override it.The root className of the height is **.ps-sidebar-container**

**In css file like SideBar.css:**

```
.ps-sidebar-container{
    height: 100vh !important; //to overwrite default css use !important
}
```

**The root className of some elements:**

- For adjust the heigth of SideBar style : **.ps-sidebar-container**
- For adjust the Menu style : **.ps-menu-root**
- For adjust the MenuItems style : **.ps-menu-root >ul>li**

This will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to BHARATH V K's answer:

CSS selectors for react-pro-sidebar v1.0.0:

```
//sidebar text color
.ps-menu-root{
color: red !important;
}

//hover over menuitems color
.ps-menu-button:hover {
background-color: red  !important;
color: black  !important;
}

//text and background color for submenu
.ps-submenu-content {
color: black !important;
background-color: red  !important;
}
```

I had to add !important tags in order to overwrite the existing css.
In order to set the background color for the entire sidebar i added inline styling to the sidebar component:

```
<Sidebar backgroundColor="red"></Sidebar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, with the React Pro Sidebar, using something like updating on `document.body.scrollHeight` worked for me:

```
const [viewHeight, setViewHeight] = useState<
  string | number
>("100vh")

useEffect(() => {
  setViewHeight(document.body.scrollHeight)
}, [document.body.scrollHeight])

...

return <div style={{ height: viewHeight }}>...</div>
```